# Aptana Studio 3 - Compress CSS/Javascript and upload

Tags: file-upload, ftp, aptana3

Hy everybody,
I've an Aptana Project already synched with an ftp connection to my deploy server.
Everytime I save a script,Aptana to upload it to FTP server through the Deploy Options.
Now I wonder if there is some Ruble or similar plugin/script that can do the following steps:
I edit the file and save it -> aptana save the uncompressed file on my local hard drive (I'll need to put it on version control) then create a minified/obfuscated version and upload it to ftp.
Is it possible?

I've already created a Ruble that compress my CSS and Javascript files through YIUCompressor but I don't know how to retrieve the FTP informations of every specific project and the upload only the minified version.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks